# jQuery colorpicker as slider with grey color range

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to build a `javascript` function on my website to switch the text color within a grey scale of colors. I've searched on google but found nothing as I wanted it. What do I go about creating the range (probably calculated from a `start` and `end` values) and reading the user input's on a slider to know what to do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any ready-made solutions, but you can use the [Slider](http://jqueryui.it/demos/slider) control from jQueryI UI to create a one-dimensional color picker.  I put together a [quick jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66JJf/1/) to demonstrate.  When the user moves the slider, the "slide" event fires and my function changes the background color of a div.  You can change the styling of the slider and the #color div to suit your needs.

Comment: That's most of what I needed to know. Thank you :)